# How to use multiple fonts for each combobox item in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I want to show items in combo box like this.

[As shown in this image per item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWMQB.png)

Is it possible?
You can answer me in both c# or vb (for WPF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this easily by using data binding with item template inside comboBox as following:

First of all you need to create item template for your ComboBox, which can be done in many ways, Iam going to use the simplest way as following:

```
<ComboBox Width="200" Height="35" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HintText}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run>( </Run>
                        <Run FontFamily="{Binding HintFontFamily}" Text="{Binding HintText}"></Run>
                        <Run> )</Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Then I am going to create the view Model for ComboBox item and assign the DataContext for the main window to make the binding works correctly

Item view Model:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HintText { get; set; }
    public string HintFontFamily { get; set; }
}
```

Main window (or your view) code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ICollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Items = new List<ItemViewModel>()
        {
            new ItemViewModel()
            {
                Name="First element",
                HintText="First font",
                HintFontFamily="Lucida Handwriting"
            },
            new ItemViewModel(){
               Name="Second element",
                HintText="Second font",
                HintFontFamily="Track"
            }
        };
        //set the datacontext which is the binding source
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Finally the result you get:
[image: Final result]