# Non-installed fonts not working when using in Data Binding Property of combo-box?

Tags: c#, wpf

Before some days, I asked a que. on stackoverflow [At This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963788/how-to-use-multiple-fonts-for-each-combobox-item-in-wpf)

I recieved an answer this works fine but only with the installed fonts

my code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    public ICollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
      Items = new List<ItemViewModel>()
      {
        new ItemViewModel()
        {
            Name="First element",
            EnglishText="Preface",
            HindiText = "This is also Jokerman",
            HintFontFamily="Lucida Handwriting",
            EngFontFamily = "pack://application:,,,/F/#DevLys 010 Bold" //Problem is here because this font is not installed in my pc so my program use default Microsoft Sans Serif as substituted.
        },
        new ItemViewModel()
        {
            Name="First element",
            EnglishText="Preface",
            HindiText = "This is also Jokerman",
            HintFontFamily="Lucida Handwriting",
            EngFontFamily = "pack://application:,,,/F/#DevLys 010 Bold" // Same problem here.
        }
      };
    //set the datacontext which is the binding source
    DataContext = this;
   }
 }
```

My designer code (WPF) :

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="Indexbox" FontSize="20" Background="Black"  BorderBrush="White" Height="28" Width="151" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="Indexbox_SelectionChanged" Canvas.Top="38" Canvas.Left="10">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{Binding HintFontFamily}" Text="{Binding EnglishText}" Foreground="LightGreen" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ComboHindi" Foreground="Orange" FontFamily="{Binding EngFontFamily}" FontSize="18"><Run Text=" ("/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="{Binding HindiText}"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text=")" /></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Is there any way I can use Private fonts in this situation.
I have read lot of articles on Private Font Collection but no one works in this program. I am using Material Design theme in my program.

**I also tried with this**

```
   <TextBlock x:Name="ComboHindi" Foreground="Orange" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/F/#DevLys 010 Bold" FontSize="18"><Run Text=" ("/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text="{Binding HindiText}"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text=")" /></TextBlock>
```

But this also not works.

Something not right in the code.

**The output image is here : ** [image: Output Image....]

Comment: Is "DevLys 010 Bold" really the name of the font?

Comment: Yes I tried with both file name as well as font name. The format of font is also ttf. I have tried with multiple fonts but no one works. But the same fonts are working in my another applications.

Comment: I think i am not using the right logic in this application. The problem is with code which can be fix in designer or in code file.

Comment: In my previous app i use 'PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection(); pfc.AddFontFile('WebAkharThick.ttf'); c.font = new font(pfc.Families[0], 15, FontStyle.Regular); ' This works fine in my win form app but now wpf has no font property and here i am usind data template also.

Comment: Can I download the .ttf file from somwhere?

Comment: Ok i will upload and the share the onedrive link with you in next 5 minutes.

Comment: Here is a .rar link which include three fonts (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuBhkbUXBDuZj3sI6_cKJ0YGxEAR)

Comment: The name of font DevLys 010 and the file name is DevLys 010 Bold. I have tried both but the code posted above is from my last edit. I also try with another two fonts as well (with font names not file names.)